# Escape underscore '_' in PostgreSQL trim() function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, trim

How to escape underscore '_' in PostgreSQL `trim()` function?

I try to remove `'vt_'` from begining of text (for example `'vt_test'` ) using `trim()` function:

```
select trim(leading 'vt_' from 'vt_test');
select ltrim('vt_test', 'vt_');
select ltrim('vt_test', 'vt\_');
select ltrim('vt_test', 'vt\\_');
```

Returns:

```
est
```

But I would like to get:

```
test
```

I can do that using `replace()` but I would like to know why `trim()` doesn't work.

Tested on Postgres 12 and 11.

**SUMMARY**

1. Function `trim` removes all leading instances of the listed characters - the order of the characters doesn't matter. You get the same result using
   `trim(leading '_tv' from 'vt_test')`.
2. I think, that the best solution is to use `select regexp_replace('vt_test', '^vt_', '')` because I only want to remove this leading string only if `vt_` exists at the begining (I'm sorry, but I didn't mention it before).

Thanks **a_horse_with_no_name**, **Mureinik** and **Erwin Brandstetter** for help!

Comment: The order of the characters doesn't matter. You get the same result using `trim(leading '_tv' from 'vt_test')`

Answer (score 2):

[`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) works as expected: It removes **all** leading instances of the listed characters. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL):

> trim([leading | trailing | both] [characters] from string)

> Remove the longest string containing only characters from *`characters`*
> (a space by default) from the start, end, or both ends (`both` is the
> default) of *`string`*

So `vt_t` is removed, not just `vt_`.

The issue is unrelated to the underscore `_`, which has no special meaning in this context.

The fastest alternative for the particular task:

```
SELECT right('vt_test', -3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here isn't escaping, `ltrim` is just the wrong tool for the job. According to the documentation, this function will

> Remove the longest string containing only characters from characters (a space by default) from the start of string.

You could use `regexp_replace` to get the desired effect:

```
select regexp_replace('vt_test', '^vt_', '')
```